# Change root password in YaST

Tags: user-interface, root, opensuse, change-password

Is it not possible to change `root` account details in `YaST`? Must one use (for example) `su` from `bash`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to change root passw from yast2.

1. open `yast2`
2. go to `Manage groups and users`
3. at tab users check the `filter` to show you `System users` instead of `Local
       users`
4. search for `root` and click `edit`

It was many times check through Suse 11.1 -> 12.2

Comment: Thanks java_xof. Clearly wasn't looking at all the GUI options :( You too!

Comment: No need to be sad :) - GUI's can be tricky and lots of options are hidden one can say - so that's why to have console around is precious!